# Chrome renders WebM Video "darker" than other browsers / media players

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video, mp4, webm

I have a video that gets served in MP4 or WebM formats, depending on browser support. I noticed that in chrome, the WebM is noticeably darker than when viewing the files locally in VLC, or even another browser such as Firefox:

#### Chrome

[image: Chrome WebM vs MP4]

#### Firefox

[image: Firefox WebM vs MP4]

The original issue was with videos that I was re-encoding myself with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2M output.webm
```

For reference, here is the input file technical information (according to `ffmpeg`):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-01-11T18:48:36.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:12.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2114 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 1280x508, 2105 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-11T18:48:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

I thought it might be related to the CLI options I was passing in, so I tried playing around with some other [encoding option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) (such as using Constant Quality (CQ) mode and two-pass encoding) but still saw the brightness differences in Chrome. After that, I noticed these same issues on media that was automatically encoded from [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), and I figured if I am seeing the differences there, it probably doesn't have anything to do with my encoding option flags.

Before I go too much down the rabbit hole here, is there anything I can control with this? Or is this just an issue with the decoder Chrome happens to be using (which is different that what VLC or Firefox is using).

### UPDATE

See [this comment](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25708/chrome-renders-webm-video-darker-than-other-browsers-media-players#comment36414_25708) from a cross post, which links to a Chromium bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=851216 - as being the root cause. If you disable hardware-accelerated video decoding within chrome, the "discoloration" goes away. As of July 2019, the bug is still unresolved.

Comment: my guess is that the colorspace isn't correctly mapping somewhere along the line. In ffmpeg you can force this by adding `--colormatrix bt709` to the libx264 parameters

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll search about colorspace more a bit, but I'm not using `libx264` to encode the video. I'm using `libvpx-vp9`. Running `ffmpeg -h encoder=libvpx-vp9`, I don't see any options that look like it would help control the color space.

Comment: sorry, hadn't noticed WebM reference (too busy skim-reading!) ... for WebM/VP9 try `-colorspace bt709` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still seeing the issue after that. I _think_ my input is reporting it has a color space of `yuv420p(tv, smpte170m)` (see my edited post above for all the metadata), so I tried running the encoder with `-colorspace smpte170m` but it doesn't fix the issue. To be honest, I'm not _exactly_ sure what that metadata is telling me (I'm trying to go off [this ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorspace)), so although I might be spinning my wheels these seem like promising leads. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Ah ha, I cross-posted this to https://video.stackexchange.com/q/25708/24177, and a helpful user was able to point me to a Chromium bug report - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=851216 - which confirms my suspicions: this is a browser bug and is _not_ related to how I'm encoding the video. Hopefully this will get fixed soon.

Comment: good find. historically colorspace issues seem to drag on a bit (not enough people care about subtle changes!) but as it's a Windows related issue maybe the new Microsoft folks on the Edge team using Chromium will be able to help...